# Two Extremely unusual Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I've implemented a Drag n Drop (android version 11)

After implementing it, sometimes it throws these Errors...
Any of you know what are these errors? I can't seem to find any information about them.

Error 1:

```
Unable to transfer touch focus
```

Error 2:

```
Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle.
```

The code is in this page:
[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567086/on-drag-listener-multiple-if-statements)
(I want to avoid duplicates)

Thanks!

Comment: Under what circumstances do these errors arise?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It happens when you touch the button quite gently instead of moving it. Sure, I've added a link to another question where the code is. Thanks!